# JavaFX playing a sound throws error

Tags: eclipse, javafx, compiler-errors, media-player

I am trying to make a simple application that plays a song on startup. The compilation goes fine, but nothing plays when i launch it (and it should) and when i click my Button, Eclipse throws bunch of errors at me. My program consists of : `AudioPlayerController`class,  `Main`class , `AudioPlayer.fxml`file. Here's my code :

**Controller class:**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class AudioPlayerController {

    @FXML
    private  Button button;
    @FXML
    private  MenuItem closeItem;

    private  MediaPlayer player;

    private  void enableControls() {
        button.setDisable(false);               
    }

    public void closeItem(ActionEvent event)    {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public void button1() {
        if(player.getStatus().equals(MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING)) {
            player.pause();
            System.out.println("paused");
        } else {
            player.play();
            System.out.println("playing");
        }       
    }

    public void startup() {
        initPlayer("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/javafx/JavaRap_Audio.mp4");
        player.play();
    }

    private  void initPlayer(String url) {
        Media md=new Media(url);
        player=new MediaPlayer(md);
        player.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                enableControls();
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
        Parent root = null;

        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AudioPlayer.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        AudioPlayerController apc= new AudioPlayerController();
        apc.startup();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cz.vutbr.feec.bmds.cv3.AudioPlayerController.tlacitko(AudioPlayerController.java:38)
    ... 58 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cz.vutbr.feec.bmds.cv3.AudioPlayerController.tlacitko(AudioPlayerController.java:38)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: You should not initialize your controller using the `new` keyword. Instead, you should fetch it from the FXMLoader using `loader.getController()`. First create a FXMLoader instance by using `FXMLoader loader = FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AudioPlayer.fxml"));` and then you can get the root element by `root = loader.load()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert the `Parent root` to a `FXMLLoader root`. Change it to `FXMLLoader` and make sure that your FXML file is in the correct folder. Then, load your class like this:

```
try {
    FXMLLoader root = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AudioPlayer.fxml"));
    scene.setRoot((Parent) root.load());
    AudioPlayerController controller = root.<AudioPlayerController> getController();
}
```

Comment: Even tho theres a little typo ( AudioPlayerControllercontroller controller) it helped !!! Thanks alot !!

Comment: My apologies. There were too much "controllers" together :) Fixed!